# How to create a quiz with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need help coding a quiz for Japanese.
I have the website made & database but I don't know ajax or javascript.
I've searched for tutorials for I can't find what i'm looking for..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0xDb.jpg
I need database of questions or randomly choose my database of questions w/ timer.
User types answer and hits enter to submit if right or wrong it +'s either and moves to next question.
Start & Stop button wipes wrong and right and resets timer.
I'm not very good with php.

**style.css**

```css
#bg {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  z-index: -10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header{
 background: #000;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 margin: 30px 300px 30px 300px;
}
nav ul li{
 padding: 5px;
 color: white;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a{
 color: white;
}

.l.btn.btn-default{
 margin: 0px 1px 5px 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#holder{
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
#answer{
 width: 40%;
 overflow:hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.list-group1{
 width: 60%;
 float: left;
 overflow:hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.list-group2{
 width: 40%;
 float: right;
 overflow:hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.col-sm-5.col-xs-6{
 position: relative;
    left: 285px;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.col-sm-2.col-xs-2{
 position: relative;
    left: 285px;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.postimg{
 width: 50%;
 height: 30%;
}
.downloadimg{
 width: 30%;
 height: 20%;
}
.panel-body{
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
 
  <?php

session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <header>
  <title>Quiz</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/reload.js"></script>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <img src="images/bg1.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
  <nav>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="">Quiz</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/1606566483004459/"target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <body onload="process()">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div onmousedown='return false;'class="panel-heading"><b><?php echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user']. ".<br>";?></b></div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <div>
       <li><a href="logout.php?logout">Logout</a></li>
       <li><a href="newpw.php">Change Password</a></li>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-6">
    <div class="p panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <center>
    <ul class="list-group1">
     <li id="questionsbox" onmousedown='return false;'class="list-group-item"><b>日本語</b></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-group2">
     <li onmousedown='return false;'class="list-group-item"><b>Timer | </b></li>
     <li onmousedown='return false;'class="list-group-item"><b>Correct | </b></li>
     <li onmousedown='return false;'class="list-group-item"><b>Wrong | </b></li>
    </ul>
    
    <td><input class="list-group-item" id="answer" type="text" name="answer" maxlength="10" placeholder="anwser" required /></td>
    <button class="l btn btn-default1" type="submit" name="start_btn">Start</button>
    <button class="l btn btn-default2" type="submit" name="stop_btn">Stop</button>
    </center>
    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 </body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

**quiz.php**

Comment: Sorry this is too general a question for this place

Comment: keep searching and write some code

Comment: If you aren't very good with php, this sounds like the perfect website you are creating! You will get lots of practice. Then when you are stuck with something more concrete, come back and we can take a look then!

Comment: i have no idea where to start..

Comment: Google is a great place to start. There are tons of tutorials about all things php.

Comment: It's not giving me what I need, I need a database that it randomly chooses a question and displays it in the textbox.